# Time complexity for a nested for loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given the following nested for loop:

```
for (int i=n; i>1; i=i/2):
    for (int j=i; j<n; j=j*2)
        # O(1) expression
```

What would the time complexity of the entire loop be? My answer is O(log(n)*log(n)) but I'm not sure if it is right.

Comment: Yes, the answer is O(log(n)  * log(n)), but it may not be for the reason that you think. How did you arrive at that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place to use the maxim

> When in doubt, work inside out!

That is, start by taking the innermost loop and replacing it with an expression indicating how much work it's doing, then repeat this until you're done.

In your case, the innermost loop is

```
for (int j=i; j<n; j=j*2)
    # O(1) expression
```

Now, how much work does this do? To answer that, let's think about how the loop works. On each iteration, the value of j doubles from what it was before. Since j begins at i, the values that j takes on will be i, 2i, 4i, 8i, etc., and more generally on the kth iteration of the loop the value of j will be 2<sup>k</sup>·i. The loop terminates once this value is equal to or exceeds n, which happens when

> 2<sup>k</sup> · i = n
>
> 2<sup>k</sup> = n / i
>
> k = lg(n / i)

So this means we're going to run the loop for Θ(log (n / i)) iterations. If we substitute this into the original loop, we're left with this code:

```
for (int i=n; i>1; i=i/2):
    Do Θ(log (n / i)) work;
```

So how much overall work does that end up being? Well, the outer loop will run once with i = n, then once with i = n/2, then once with i = n/4, etc., so the total work done is

> Θ(log (n/n) + log(n/(n/2)) + log(n/(n/4)) + ... + log(n / 1))
>
> = Θ(log 1 + log 2 + log 4 + log 8 + ... + log n)
>
> = Θ(log 2<sup>0</sup> + log 2<sup>1</sup> + log 2<sup>2</sup> + log 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + log 2<sup>log n</sup>)
>
> Θ(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + log n)

Remember that 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + k = k(k + 1) / 2 = Θ(k<sup>2</sup>), so the total work done here is

> Θ(0 + 1 + 2 + ... + log n)
>
> = **Θ(log<sup>2</sup> n)**.

The key techniques in arriving at this answer were starting from the inside, connecting logarithms with the number of loop iterations performed when repeatedly doubling something in size, and the formula for 1 + 2 + ... + k.